# See only current day's events on iCal

Tags: osx-lion, calendar.app

Is it possible in iCal (OS X Lion), when one switches to "day view," to only see the events or tasks that belong to the day being displayed and not to the previous or subsequent days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that there is.  If you print the current day though, only that day's events show up on the right hand side of the page.